# specifing XML tags to read in a variable

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm reading an XML file using PowerShell and I need to extract the value of a specific tag, but i'd like to be able to have that tag in a variable.

If I do this:

```psh
[xml]$content = Get-Content "$($splitsinglehost[1])$XPfilelocation$XMLfiletoRead"
$XMLvalue= $content.BT9000_XML_FILE.Config_SETX.I_Camera_Manufacturer
```

it works, the value I'm looking for is stored in `$XMLvalue` as a string.

but if I do:

```psh
$XMLinfo = "BT9000_XML_FILE.Config_SETX.I_Security_Module_Manufacturer"
[xml]$content = Get-Content "$($splitsinglehost[1])$XPfilelocation$XMLfiletoRead"
$XMLvalue= $content.$XMLinfo
```

it doesn't work.  If I try to output the value of `$XMLvalue` as a string it's blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `$XMLinfo` an [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) and use `SelectSingleNode()` for selecting the node:

```psh
$XMLinfo = '/BT9000_XML_FILE/Config_SETX/I_Security_Module_Manufacturer'
[xml]$content = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml'
$XMLvalue = $content.SelectSingleNode($XMLinfo).innerText
```

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you veyr much for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So i don't know if you can get it to work in the way you are trying to use it.

You can do this though:

```
$XMLinfo = "BT9000_XML_FILE.Config_SETX.I_Security_Module_Manufacturer"
[xml]$content = Get-Content "$($splitsinglehost[1])$XPfilelocation$XMLfiletoRead"
$XMLinfo = $XMLinfo.Replace('.','/')
$XMLvalue= $content.SelectNodes($XMLinfo) | % { $_.innerText }
```